# LaTeX gives error in the following code

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass{article}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\DeclareMathOperator{\RelU}{RelU}
%\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subfloat}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\dd}[1]{\mathrm{d}#1}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
\title{ A deep learning approach}
\author{Ghul$^{1,2}$, Javaid$^{1*}$, \\
$^{1}$COMSATS University Islamabad 44000, Pakistan\\
$^{2}$University of Engineering and Technology, Mardan, 23200, Pakistan\\
%$^{2}$CAMS, Dept of Biomedical Technology, KSU, Riyadh 11633, Saudi Arabia\\
%$^{3}$FE, Dalhousie University, Halifax, NS B3J 4R2, Canada\\
$^{*}$Corresponding author: www.njavaid.com, nadeemjavaidqau@gmail.com
}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Short term load forecasting; deep learning; smart grid; factored conditional restricted boltzmann machine; conditional restricted boltzmann machine; rectified linear unit.
\end{IEEEkeywords}


\section*{Nomenclature}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Nomenclature}
\begin{IEEEdescription}[\IEEEusemathlabelsep\IEEEsetlabelwidth{$V_1,V_2,V_3$}]
\item[$E$]  {Error function}
\item[$v$]  {Visible layer}
\item[$u$]  {History layer}
\item[$h$]  Hidden layer
\item[$a$] Visible layer bias
\item[$b$] Hidden layer bias
\item[$w^{vh}$] Bi-directional weight matrix between hidden and visible layers
\item[$w^{uh}$] Unidirectional weight matrix between hidden and visible layers
\item[$w^{uv}$] Unidirectional weight matrix between visible and history layers
\item[$Sigmoid$]  Sigmoidal activation function
%\item[$RelU$]  Rectified linear unit activation function
\item[$w^{vh}_{t+1}$] Updated bi-directional weight matrix between hidden and visible layers
\item[$w^{uh}_{t+1}$] Updated unidirectional weight matrix between hidden and visible layers
\item[$w^{uv_{t+1}}$] Updated unidirectional weight matrix between visible and history layers
\item[$a_{t+1}$] Updated bias of visible layer
\item[$b_{t+1}$] Updated bias of hidden layer
\item[$\hat a$]  Visible layer dynamic bias
\item[$\hat b$]  Hidden layer dynamic bias
\item[$w^v$] Visible layer weight
\item[$w^y$] Style layer weight
\item[$w^h$] Hidden layer weight
\item[$A^u$] History layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat a$
\item[$A^v$] Visible layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat a$
\item[$A^y$] Style layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat a$
\item[$B^u$] History layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat b$
\item[$B^y$] Style layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat b$
\item[$B^h$] Hidden layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat b$
\item[$A^u_{t+1}$] Updated history layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat a$
\item[$A^v_{t+1}$] Updated visible layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat a$
\item[$A^y_{t+1}$] Updated style layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat a$
\item[$B^u_{t+1}$] Updated history layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat b$
\item[$B^y_{t+1}$] Updated style layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat b$
\item[$B^h_{t+1}$] Updated hidden layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat b$
\item[$\hat a_{t+1}$]  Updated visible layer dynamic bias
\item[$\hat b_{t+1}$] Updated hidden layer dynamic bias
\item[$RelU$] Rectified linear unit activation function
\item[$\circ$] Hadamard product
\item[$RMSE$] Root mean square error
\item[$r$] Correlation coefficient
\item[$MAPE$] Mean absolute percentage error
\item[$R_t$] Real value
\item[$F_t$] Forecast value
\item[$\mu _R$] Mean of real values
\item[$\mu_F$] Mean of forecasted values\\
\end{IEEEdescription}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please make your example more minimal? THere are a ton of packages that I am very sure you don't need to replicate your issue. Quoting the exact error message you get is also generally a good idea.

Comment: The error message one recieves is the following `Environment IEEEkeywords undefined.` This environment is efined in the `IEEEtran` documentclass, so if you replace `article` by `IEEEtran` your document will be compilable.

Comment: Please make this executable in the article environment. Thanks

Comment: Apart from you issue: Please make sure that you don't load packages more than once (e.g. `mathtools`) and please also mind the load order of some packages (e.g. `cleveref`)

Comment: No problem remove the packages which are not required in this environment.

Comment: As I don't see a good reason for trying to use `IEEEtran` environments in a document based on the `article` class: Is this question related to your [previous one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481023/134144)? If this is the case, I definitely agree with [Mico's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481023/latex-template-of-wiley-publisher-of-journal-energy-and-technology#comment1215601_481023)

Comment: Please use article envoirnment. Instead of IEEEtrans

Comment: @GhulamHafeez What do you mean by “please use article environment”? You ***cannot*** use `IEEEkeywords` in the `article` class, because it is ***not*** defined in it.

Comment: @egreg - I would guess that the OP is hoping to get some *Ersatz* definitions for environments and macros provided by the `IEEEtran` document class. At least, that's the hunch I relied on when I wrote my answer...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you load the [IEEEtrantools](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/tools) package. It provides quite a few of the macros and environments of the `IEEEtran` document class, for use with other document classes -- such as the `article` class. For instance, the `IEEEtrantools` package provides an environment called `IEEEdescription`, which you appear to use.

The IEEEtrantools package does not, though, provide code for an environment called `IEEEkeywords`. You may want to try something like

```
\newenvironment{IEEEkeywords}{\raggedright\noindent\textsc{Keywords}:}{\par}
```

to be inserted in the preamble.

Some additional comments. (a) The `cleveref` package should be loaded **last**. (b) I can think of no good reason for typesetting the words Sigmoid, RMSE, and MAPE in math mode. (c) I think it's rather questionable to write `boltzmann`; do write `Boltzmann` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%% New instructions:
\usepackage{geometry}  % choose suitable page parameters
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\newenvironment{IEEEkeywords}{\raggedright\noindent\textsc{Keywords}:}{\par}

%% Rest of preamble may remain unchanged
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\DeclareMathOperator{\RelU}{RelU}
%\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subfloat}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\dd}[1]{\mathrm{d}#1}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{cleveref}  % this package should be loaded LAST

\title{ A deep learning approach}
\author{Ghul$^{1,2}$, Javaid$^{1*}$, \\
$^{1}$COMSATS University Islamabad 44000, Pakistan\\
$^{2}$University of Engineering and Technology, Mardan, 23200, Pakistan\\
%$^{2}$CAMS, Dept of Biomedical Technology, KSU, Riyadh 11633, Saudi Arabia\\
%$^{3}$FE, Dalhousie University, Halifax, NS B3J 4R2, Canada\\
$^{*}$Corresponding author: www.njavaid.com, nadeemjavaidqau@gmail.com}

\usepackage{lipsum} % provides filler text
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Short term load forecasting; deep learning; smart grid; factored conditional restricted Boltzmann machine; conditional restricted Boltzmann machine; rectified linear unit.
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\tableofcontents % optional

\section*{Nomenclature}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Nomenclature}

\begin{IEEEdescription}[\IEEEusemathlabelsep%
      \IEEEsetlabelwidth{Sigmoid}]
\item[$E$]  {Error function}
\item[$v$]  {Visible layer}
\item[$u$]  {History layer}
\item[$h$]  Hidden layer
\item[$a$] Visible layer bias
\item[$b$] Hidden layer bias
\item[$w^{vh}$] Bi-directional weight matrix between hidden and visible layers
\item[$w^{uh}$] Unidirectional weight matrix between hidden and visible layers
\item[$w^{uv}$] Unidirectional weight matrix between visible and history layers
\item[Sigmoid]  Sigmoidal activation function
%\item[$RelU$]  Rectified linear unit activation function
\item[$w^{vh}_{t+1}$] Updated bi-directional weight matrix between hidden and visible layers
\item[$w^{uh}_{t+1}$] Updated unidirectional weight matrix between hidden and visible layers
\item[$w^{uv_{t+1}}$] Updated unidirectional weight matrix between visible and history layers
\item[$a_{t+1}$] Updated bias of visible layer
\item[$b_{t+1}$] Updated bias of hidden layer
\item[$\hat a$]  Visible layer dynamic bias
\item[$\hat b$]  Hidden layer dynamic bias
\item[$w^v$] Visible layer weight
\item[$w^y$] Style layer weight
\item[$w^h$] Hidden layer weight
\item[$A^u$] History layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat a$
\item[$A^v$] Visible layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat a$
\item[$A^y$] Style layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat a$
\item[$B^u$] History layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat b$
\item[$B^y$] Style layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat b$
\item[$B^h$] Hidden layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat b$
\item[$A^u_{t+1}$] Updated history layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat a$
\item[$A^v_{t+1}$] Updated visible layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat a$
\item[$A^y_{t+1}$] Updated style layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat a$
\item[$B^u_{t+1}$] Updated history layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat b$
\item[$B^y_{t+1}$] Updated style layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat b$
\item[$B^h_{t+1}$] Updated hidden layer connection for dynamic bias $\hat b$
\item[$\hat a_{t+1}$]  Updated visible layer dynamic bias
\item[$\hat b_{t+1}$] Updated hidden layer dynamic bias
\item[$RelU$] Rectified linear unit activation function
\item[$\circ$] Hadamard product
\item[RMSE] Root mean square error
\item[$r$] Correlation coefficient
\item[MAPE] Mean absolute percentage error
\item[$R_t$] Real value
\item[$F_t$] Forecast value
\item[$\mu _R$] Mean of real values
\item[$\mu_F$] Mean of forecasted values
\end{IEEEdescription}
\end{document}
```